# one page scrolling website hide images on menu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, vertical-scrolling

I have been working on this code to have images change as each section of a single page website comes into the viewport. It is mostly working except that, if you click the side menu, (the .tvMenu on click) the page will scroll to the relevant section but as it does all the images show up as the various sections scroll past the viewport. I know the reason is that the onclick hides the images aND the scroll unhides them. 
The only way I can get it to do what i want is to through an error into the javscript. (not happy about that). BTW i'm fairly new at this. I've used some other code found on various searches.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    function filterPath(string) {
        return string.replace(/^\//, '')
            .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/, '')
            .replace(/\/$/, '');
    }
    var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
    var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

    $('a[href*=#]').each(function () {
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (locationPath == thisPath && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname) && this.hash.replace(/#/, '')) {
            var $target = $(this.hash),
                target = this.hash;
            if (target) {
                var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
                $(this).click(function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $(scrollElem).animate({
                        scrollTop: targetOffset
                    }, 1000, function () {
                        location.hash = target;
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    });


    function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i < argLength; i++) {
            var el = arguments[i],
                $scrollElement = $(el);
            if ($scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0) {
                return el;
            } else {
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
                var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop() > 0;
                $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
                if (isScrollable) {
                    return el;
                }
            }
        }
        return [];
    }

});


$(".tvMenu").click(function () {
    var btnId = $(this).attr('href');
    var targetImg = parseInt(btnId.substring(1), 10);

    var activeDiv = $("img.tv_active").attr("id");
    var activeImg = parseInt(activeDiv.substring(2), 10);

    for(var hideImg = 0; hideImg < 11; hideImg++){
        if(targetImg != hideImg){
             $("#wrap" + ERROR Not hideImg + " img").removeClass("tv_active").fadeOut(800);
        }
        else{
            $("#wrap" + targetImg + " img").addClass("tv_active").fadeIn(800);
        }
    }

});


var lastScrollTop = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
    scrollClick(this);
});

function scrollClick(thisObject) {

    var st = $(thisObject).scrollTop();
    var winH = $(window).height();
    var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();
    var docH = $(document).height() / 12;
    var t = 0;

    if (st < lastScrollTop) {

       // test readout back to screen  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "up" + " " + st;
        for (t = 0; t <= 11; t++) {


            if (scrollPos > (((docH * t) + 1) - (winH * 0.66)) && scrollPos < ((docH * (t + 1)) - (winH * 0.66))) {


                $("#sidebar-wrapper").removeClass("active");
                $("#wrap" + t + " img").addClass("tv_active").fadeIn(800);
            } else {
                $("#wrap" + t + " img").removeClass("tv_active").fadeOut(800);
            }
        }
    } else if (st > lastScrollTop) {


       // test readout back to screen  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "down" + " " + st;
        for (t = 0; t < 11; t++) {

            if (scrollPos > (((docH * t) + 1) - (winH * 0.33)) && scrollPos < ((docH * (t + 1)) - (winH * 0.33))) {

                $("#sidebar-wrapper").removeClass("active");
                $("#wrap" + t + " img").addClass("tv_active").fadeIn(800);
            } else if (scrollPos > ((docH * 11))) {
                for (s = 0; s < 11; s++) {
                    $("#wrap" + s + " img").removeClass("tv_active").fadeOut(800);
                }
            } else {
                $("#wrap" + t + " img").removeClass("tv_active").fadeOut(800);
            }
        }
    }
    lastScrollTop = st;
}
});
```

Comment: what images are you talking about? do you have a fiddle that showcases your problem?
Or a live link?

Comment: how do i share a fiddle?

Comment: paste the relevant code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/) (html in the html section, css in the css... you get the idea), hit _run_ to test it. when it all works out, click _save_ on top, then you can share the link

Comment: @BenPhilipp -  my test server.

[link](http://tdr-webtest.co.uk/test/index3.html#0)

Comment: You really need to put this in a fiddle. Your link only shows the current situation (with the error-hack you don't really want), in order for us to figure out how to fix it without that error-hack, we first need to see what happens without that hack (your description is nog enough), and then we need to be able to modify the code and test it (or at least I do). We can't do that on your test server.

Comment: Hi @myfunkyside here is the fiddle not sure why the images won't load, Fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/timmob/95b1n0L9/1), and here is a link to a version of the site without the error code. [link](http://tdr-webtest.co.uk/test/index5.html) thanks